# Why doesn't css code for a dropdown menu's box-shadow work in ul li ul{}, but in ul li:hover ul{}?

Tags: css

It's css for a dropdown menu's box-shadow. I can't figure out why it doesn't work in line 56, but works in line 45. It seems the editor knows why. Do you know why?
[line 56 box-shadow is lighter, and it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4i4e.png)

```css
nav ul li:hover ul{
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px purple;
}
nav ul li ul{
  margin-left: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  width: 10rem;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: hotpink;
  border-radius: 5px
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px purple;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I could achieve the box-shallow effect by adding it after :hover. I just wanted to understand why I couldn't add it to the menu directly without the pseudo-element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my dropdown menu, it works for me:

```
     .drop{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }
    .pop{
        display: none;
        position:fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        padding: 0;
        margin: auto;
        min-height: fit-content;
        min-width: fit-content;
        background-color: orangered;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .drop:hover .pop{
        display: block;
    }
```

just add you own code.
i hope this is useful.